# restify JSON client returns DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT error

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, restify

I have server runing on heroku with heroku SSL addon. 
Server is created with this options:

```
name: 'ServerName',
version: '1.0.0',
```

And the I run server like this:

```
    server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)
```

And it works fine, I can call my api for example: https://myapp.herokuapp.com/some-path. SSL cert on heroku is self-signed so there is a big warning in webbrowser but I can click continue and it works.

When I want to call my server with restify JSON client, created as follows:

```
var client   = restify.createJsonClient({
    url: 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com'
});
```

and then call some api like this `client.get('/some-path',...)` then client returns error:

```
DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
```

I tried to set option `rejectUnauthorized` on both server and client (as constructor option) but it didnt help...

Answer (score 4):

I've just tested on my own HTTPS server with a self-signed certificate. `rejectUnauthorized` on the client side should definitely solve it for you

```
var restify = require('restify'),

    client = restify.createJsonClient({
        url: 'https://127.0.0.1/booking',
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }),

    assert = require('assert');

describe('/booking/ component\'s JSON-HAL HTTP API description', function () {
    it('responds with status 200', function (done) {
        client.get('/', function (error, request, response) {
            assert(!error);
            assert.strictEqual(response.statusCode, 200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

As soon as I remove the `rejectUnauthorized` option, the test fails with `DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`.

Answer (score 4):

For me `rejectUnauthorized` didn't work.
Finally I ended up with:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

And it works...